# html email message in codeigniter/php

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp, html-email

This has to be simple, I'm trying to load a view file as my email message using CodeIgniter. The point is to have an HTML and not just a text-based message.

Currently, my emails are sending ok but the messages are empty if my code looks like what it does below:

Here's the relevant part of the php:

```
    $config=array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n"
  );
 $this->email->initialize($config);
 $this->email->subject('testing loading a view file');
 $msg = $this->load->view('reviews/email', '', false);
 $this->email->message($msg);
```

Here's what the reviews/email.php file looks like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body> <h1>this should be BIG</h1> this should not
          <a href="http://google.com/<? $php='login'; echo $php?>">Google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any advice you might have,

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the view incorrectly. The third parameter is supposed to be `TRUE` so that CodeIgniter will return the view as a string.

```
$msg = $this->load->view('reviews/email', '', true);
```

From http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html:

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
```

Comment: hi Kemal, thanks for the suggestion, that worked. Though the key part for my purpose, adding php code into links did not. Can you think of why this didn't work: `<a href="http://google.com/<? $php='login'; echo $php?>">google login</a>`

Comment: @timpeterson How exactly is it not working? Does the string `login` doesn't get outputted? Plus, wouldn't it be much easier if you just echo the string? I see no point why you should store it in a variable first. In fact there's no need to use print the string using PHP. Pure HTML would work just fine (Assuming it's always going to be the same).

Comment: sorry, it does work in the sense that clicking the link takes you to the appropriate URL. I was confused because if you hover over the link it shows you a URL pointing to my email server followed by alot of random characters like this: `http://email.mysite.com/adfas73j3j3jd-adsfdfk`. But yes, if you click on it, it takes you to `mysite.com/login`. This is weird, do you understand why that is happening?

Comment: That's probably because of the email server software. Perhaps it's a way of tracking outgoing visitor. But I'm not so sure about that, so you might want to google it instead.

Comment: hi Kemal, you are correct, i checked with my mail server, http://sendgrid.com, which is a really nice service incidentally, and these random characters are the tokenization of the URL for link tracking purposes.